# Update Password in Asp.net Core 2 Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

This is my Login `IAction`

**Controller**

```cs
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoginWith2fa), new { returnUrl, model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
            }

            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Now My current Email and Password is

Email : **john@gmail.com**

Password : **john@gmail.com123**

and i want Update Password **john@gmail.com123** to **john@gmail.com677**
Please Help me out from this issue ,
Thanks In advance

Comment: Hello.It's quite unclear what you are asking. You ask about updating password, but posting code about logging in. Also please take a look at [How to ask](/https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask. Please clarify your question and show what you did tried so far to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.generatepasswordresettokenasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and [`UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.resetpasswordasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

If the scenario you are handling is for a "forgotten password" then you will most likely want to send an email to the user with a link. This link will take the user to an action which takes the reset token as a query parameter. The user can then click on this link to reset their password and the `ResetPasswordAsync` call is made from there.

If this is the scenario you are looking at (your post is not specific), then you should look at the Microsoft guide here: [Enable account confirmation and password recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#enable-account-confirmation-and-password-recovery)

Some cut-down code (for illustration/didactic purposes only):

```cs
// Get the user by email - may need to be careful of casing here
IdentityUser user = _userManager.Users.First(x => x.Email == "email@example.com");

// Generate the reset token (this would generally be sent out as a query parameter as part of a 'reset' link in an email)
string resetToken = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

// Use the reset token to verify the provenance of the reset request and reset the password.
IdentityResult updateResult = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, resetToken, newPassword);
```